# Noscript temporarily allow behavior change with new browser version

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

How do I see all the scripts in the permission contextual menu so that I can allow only specific scripts?

I upgraded to the newest tor browser version 4.

With earlier tor versions, I would go to a page and I could enable or disable each individual script. I always disable scripts globally and then temporarily allow only the scripts I want.

Now, I only have one option for the specific site I visit.  I often go to sites that have other scripts that I do NOT want to allow (like scripts from facebook or twitter).

To clarify, the version of NoScript is the same between tor browser versions.  I have gone through and checked all NoScript settings to make sure they're the same, but the scripts still don't show up in the permissions menu.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Open the NoScript options.
Go to Advanced Tab.
Click on 'Trusted' sub tab.

Deselect / uncheck option that says: Cascade top document's permissions to 3rd party scripts.

Now all scripts show up.